# Why does SELECT statement seem to have returned something other than "NULL" value on finding no matching record

Tags: php, mysql

My code shown below has conditional statement in order to display the "No listings found" if the DB doesn't have any record matching the keyword based on which SELECT statement is run. I tried with search words such as 'plants', '300food' to ensure it works the way intended. What is happening here is since the SQL statement doesn't fetch any record as there is nothing in the DB matching my search word, the code below doesn't display anything which is perfectly fine. I need to display the message "No listing found". I wonder why the below condition gets met when the `$record` contains no record, ignoring the 'else' statement which is there to display the message. Any help suggestion/advise humbly appreciated.

```
if($record!=null) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($record)){
```

The complete code is here for you to see where it might be wrong. Please advise if I am doing things in a right way as far PHP syntax is concerned. Thanks for your time.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    if($_POST['search_word']!=null){
      $clean_search_word   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['search_word']);
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM webdir_user where user_category like '%$clean_search_word%' LIMIT $start, $limit"; 
      $record = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      if(!$record) {
        die('Error in SQL:'.mysqli_error());
          }
      }
    else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM webdir_user LIMIT $start, $limit";
      $record = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      if(!$record){
        die('Error in SQL:'.mysqli_error());
          } 
       } 
   }

else { // Direct page access from the top menu item.
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM webdir_user LIMIT $start, $limit";
      $record = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      if(!$record){
        die('Error in SQL:'.mysqli_error());
      } 
} 

// Data fetched from the DB.
if($record!=null) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($record)){
?>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<p class="content-p-tag-top"><?php echo $row['user_business']; ?></p>
<p class="content-p-tag">    <?php echo $row['user_category']; ?></p>
<p class="content-p-tag"><a> <?php echo $row['user_url']; ?></a></p>
</div>

<?php } } else { ?> 
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<p class="content-p-tag-top">Sorry! No listing found matching your key word!</p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**mysqli_query()** **return** : For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN queries it will return a **mysqli_result object.** For other successful queries it will return **TRUE**. **FALSE** on failure

Use **mysqli_num_rows()** for Return the number of rows in a result set:

Like

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   // record found
}else{
   // record not found
}
```

Comment: Mere word of thanks isn't enough for saving me extra hours that would have been spent struggling with this issue. It is resolved with your kind help.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info as it is very useful in avoiding further issues of similar kind.